# For Loop not working with Array in mysql php

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays, for-loop

I'm trying to pass values from an array into a variable

```
$coode = '111,222,333';

$rollnum = explode(",", $coode);
for($x = 0; $x < count($rollnum); $x++){
  $products = $db->query("SELECT name FROM studentstb WHERE roll_no=".$rollnum[$x]."");
                       while($row = $products->fetch_assoc()){
                          $stdname =$row['name'];
                       }

}
echo($stdname);
```

and i want the result to be shown as tolu,tulu,tala
i want to get those values into a variable, explode it, check the database to retrieve their names then display them.

Comment: And what is the error that you are getting? Your code will only ever show the last name, is that what you intended?

Comment: If it's the "Boolean" error message you put in your other post, that suggests that the query has not worked. Test your query in phpMyAdmin or your equivalent to see what is wrong with it.

Comment: nope, i want the result to be shown as tolu,tulu,tala

Comment: Then you need to concatenate each result to `$stdname`, not overwrite it. Or make `$stdname` an array and add to it and then display it. Or display each name inside the loop, not at the end. Is the query working now?

Comment: It's still not working

Comment: i want to get those values into a variable, explode it, check the database to retrieve their names then display them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now working,
I ignored a single quotation in the query

```
 $rollnum = explode(',', $coode);
  for($x = 0; $x < count($rollnum); $x++){
    $products = $db->query("SELECT name FROM studentstb WHERE roll_no='".$rollnum[$x]."'");
    while($row = $products->fetch_assoc()){
     $stdname[$x] =$row['name'];
    }

}
```

then i displayed it using

```
foreach ($stdname as $a){
        echo $a;
```

Comment: You also didn't use $stdname as an arrow.

Comment: $stdname is used as the variable to display the values gotten from the database.

Answer (score 0):

The method ***fetch_assoc()*** should not be defined for your PDOStatement Object ***$products*** if you are using PDO driver, but it is defined for MySQLi.

Check [PDOStatement methods list](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php) here and [those for MySQLi](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli) here.

On the other hand your variable ***$stdname*** should be an array, where you add your three values from the query.
You should then adapt your while loop content like this :

```
while($row = $products->fetch()){
//get the names in an array
$stdname[$x] = $row['name'];
}
```

And finally, make a loop to display the names at your convenience.

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems, first one is `N + 1` queries, second one is in line `$stdname = $row['name'];`

**Solution**

```
$codes = '1,2,3';

$sql = "SELECT name FROM users WHERE id IN ({$codes})";
$result = $mysqli -> query($sql);
$namesArr = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$updatedNamesArr = array_map(function ($name){
    return $name['name'];
}, $namesArr);

var_dump(implode(',', $updatedNamesArr));
```

**Output**

```
"Dmitry,Raf,Api"
```

Comment: n + 1 query problem is related to ORM, It won't occur in your case, so disregard it please.